# Use retrieved value from internal query to query with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The value I need for the now() query is the timezone from the Group model, I'm just not sure how to get it within the query.

I would like to use $reminder->group->timezone value instead of hardcoding the value in now(). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$reminders = Reminder::with('group','appointment')
             ->where('reminder_datetime', '<', Carbon::now('America/New_York'))  --> Use $reminder->group->timezone value instead of hardcoding the value
             ->get();
```

Comment: is `reminder_datetime` are column of group model?

Comment: No, it's a column of the Reminder model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will not be executed until you call the get method.

However, you need the query result of the group of reminder to reach the timezone in order to call the `now` method of Carbon inside PHP.

Because you need the timezone before retrieving the query results, that won't work.

Instead, you can get the reminder results without the where method - with timezones - and than filter the Eloquent Collection as you want in your method.